# Le nom après « Filtrer par » doit-il être au singulier ou au pluriel ?

Tags: pluriel

Le nom après « Filtrer par » doit-il toujours être au singulier ou au pluriel ? Ou alors cela dépend du contexte ?

Par exemple :

> Filtrer par nom -> On ne peut filtrer qu'avec une seule valeur à la fois
> Filtrer par étiquettes -> On peut filtrer avec de multiples valeurs en même temps

Ces deux exemples sont-il corrects ?

Comment: Un filtrage se fait un par un.

Comment: @Lambie Pas forcement, un exemple tout bête : une boutique en ligne qui vend des vêtements te permet de filtrer les vêtements par couleur(s?) et tu peux sélectionner plusieurs couleurs en même temps.

Comment: @Ren Pourquoi te demandes-tu si on doit mettre au *couleur* au singulier alors qu'on a sélectionné plusieurs couleurs ?

Comment: @jlliagre Ma question c'est est ce que je dois écrire « Filtrer par couleur » ou « Filtrer par couleurs », indépendamment du fait qu'on ai sélectionné ou pas une ou plusieurs couleurs.

Comment: Cela n'est pas vrai. Pour les couleurs, il faut séléctionner une par une. Ce sont **les résultats de la recherche** qui montrent un article pour chaque couleur.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est-ce qui n'est pas vrai ? En quoi le fait de choisir les couleurs une par une imposerait le singulier à couleurs, si c'est ce que tu veux dire ?  Pourquoi n'y aurait-il qu'un article de chaque couleur ? Pourquoi n'y aurait-il pas d'articles multicolores ?

Comment: @jlliagre Il faut lire Ren et moi. Ren a dit: "tu peux sélectionner plusieurs couleurs en même temps". Je dis que cela n'est pas vrai. Le choix ou la sélection des couleurs pour un vêtement se fait un par un, Ce sont les résultats de la recherche dans la base de donnée du site qui montrent l'article en question en plusieurs couleurs. Ou bien, on peut visualiser les couleurs pour un article en cochant une case couleur et l'article change de couleurs. Enfin,  régarde le bon marché enl ligne.

Comment: 24s.com/fr-fr/femme/… Il y a marque, couleur et taille. En dessous de chaqu'un, on peut choisir. Par exemple: Pour couleur, il a des cases: Argent, Beige, Blanc, Bleu, Bordeaux, Ecru, etc. Donc, on a filtrage par marque, par couleur et par taille. Et puis, comme c'est la France, il n'y a pas "par prix". [That's a joke]. Au moins pas dans ce magazin, "haut de gamme". Un t-shirt Max Mara vaut $315 euros. Wow.

Comment: @Lambie Ce que tu décrit n'est qu'une possibilité mais rien n'interdit à un site de proposer de n'afficher que les articles de telle ou telle couleur. C'est d'ailleurs plus ça qu'on appelle du filtrage.

Comment: @jlliagre Un site peut afficher tout ce le marchand souhaite afficher. Je répondais à Ren. J'ai un dialoque avec lui/elle. Le filtrage est une décision de la conception du site. Si j'étais toi, je descendrais du train à cette station. https://www.wizishop.fr/blog/filtres-facettes.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Le singulier est possible que ce soit un choix multiple ou pas :

> Filter par couleur

Si tu veux insister sur le fait qu'il est possible de choisir plusieurs couleurs, tu peux aussi écrire :

> Filter par couleur(s)

Comment: Est-ce-que l’utilisation du pluriel sans les parenthèses est incorrect du coup ?

Comment: Non, on peut aussi mettre *couleurs* au pluriel. Le singulier me semble plus courant et logique mais rien ne l'impose grammaticalement.

Comment: D'accord merci, c'est ce que j'avais besoin de savoir. :)

Comment: Il semble que *filtrer par <propriété>* soit une tournure récente, peut-être seulement apparue avec les tableurs et autres bases de données. Auparavant, *filtrer par* était semble-t-il toujours suivi de l'objet qui servait à filtrer (*filtrer par un prisme, par les rideaux, par aspiration, par décantation, par le vide, etc.*)  Le fait que cet usage soit donc assez lié à l'informatique peut expliquer l'absence de "jurisprudence" à propos du nombre à utiliser...

Comment: @jlliagre Ahh bien vu, cela explique pourquoi je n'ai pas pu trouver de réponse clair lors de mes recherches, d'où mon poste ici.

Comment: @LétaleD'incivilisation Désolé, j'ai relu ton message plusieurs fois mais j'ai beaucoup de mal à comprendre ce que tu as écrit. Si je ne me trompe pas, en gros tu dis qu'on essaye de remplacer "Trier objets selon critère" par une version raccourcie "Filtrer par critère" ce qui rend flou le choix du pluriel vs singulier ? C'est bien ça ?

Comment: @Ren Oui mais ce n'est qu'une idée suite à l'observation que la tournure est récente. Je ne sais pas.

Answer (score 0):

Par exemple:

> Le filtrage n’aura jamais été puissant qu’avec notre système.
> Permettez aux utilisateurs de filtrer toutes les caractéristiques de
> vos produits, peu importe ce que vous vendez.

[dyanamoprod](https://dynamoprod.fr/web/e-commerce/filtrages-ordres-avances/)

[image]

Le problème n'est pas si on doit écrire par couleurs ou par couleur. Il s'agit de se conformer aux usages du e-commerce, à mon avis. Un filtre se fait par catégorie. Alors, le pluriel n'est pas de mise.

Sur la page posté ci-dessus, on voit: filtrer par marque, par couleur, et par taille. A vous de choisir.

Comment: Merci pour ta réponse mais ce que je veux savoir c'est si je dois utiliser le singulier ou le pluriel, et non les règles du e-commerce. Par ailleurs, un seul exemple n'est pas suffisant pour justifier une utilisation ou une autre. Si tu regardes le site Décathlon tu constateras qu'ils utilisent le pluriel pour les titres des filtres.

Comment: @Ren Tu vois bien que c'est au singulier, n'est-ce pas? Et que j'ai dit que **c'est aussi un choix stylistique** et de contexte. Il vaut mieux que donner un contexte précis. N'empéche que appliquer un filtre implique un choix pour une chose à la fois, en général.

Comment: Je veux juste savoir s'il faut mettre au singulier ou au pluriel le titre de mes filtres sachant que j'ai des filtres où une seule valeur peut être sélectionnée et d'autres où on peut en sélectionner plusieurs. Ici je ne suis pas intéressée par les règles du web mais par les règles de français.

Comment: Je ne comprend pas ton contexte alors. Il n'y rien dans les règles du français qui interdisent de mettre les catégories après le mot par au singulier ou au pluriel.